# How to limit the user to only three tries to input correct password in a function?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that is password protected. I have a function with a validation loop called getPassword() that allows the user to type in password attempts as many times as they want, but now I want to limit them to only 3 attempts. Would I be able to do this in the getPassword() function or do I have to create another function?

I've tried making the getPassword() into a do while loop and used a for-loop to inside the do while to count how many times the user attempts entering the password and tried to get it to break when the counter reached 3, but that doesn't seem to get me out of the do while loop. Any suggestions?

```
void getPassword()
{
  int i = 0;
  string password = "sup";
  string userInput;
  int wrongPasswords = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    cout << "Please enter your password: " << endl; 
    cin >> userInput;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

    while (true)
    {
    if (userInput != password)
    {
      cout << "Invalid. Please try again. You can only attempt 
      password 3 times." << endl;
      wrongPasswords++;
      break;
    }//if

      if (wrongPasswords == 3)
      break; 

    }//while
  }//for
}//getPassword

Edited code:
void getPassword()
{
  string password = "sup";
  string userInput;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    cout << "Please enter your password: " << endl; 
    cin >> userInput;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

    if (userInput == password && i < 3)
    break;
   }
}//getPassword
```

Comment: What is your counter?  Where do you change it?  Where do you test it?

Comment: @ScottHunter So I tried for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) and then created a variable int = wrongPasswords that got added one every time userInput != password and I put it right before the if statement in my code

Comment: Consider a smarter exit condition on the `while` and returning bool. If the loop exits, return false. If the user enters a valid password, return true.

Comment: @wangowango That `for` loop looks better than the `while` used in the question. I'd use it instead. That just leaves you with the question of how to get whether or not the user got the password right out of the function.

Comment: What you need to do is [have a discussion with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and explain to your rubber duck why you have two different things here whose purpose is to count wrong passwords: this `for` loop, and the `wrongPasswords` variable. Your rubber duck is demanding a full explanation why it is necessary to do one task in two different ways, simultaneously. This makes no sense. This simple logical task should require only a `for` loop, or some other kind of loop with a counter variable, but not both. Your rubber duck believes that's your problem.

Comment: Why an extra loop? This only needs an `if`. "If the password is wrong, _again_, and it's already been three times: <do something>". Simple logic!

Comment: Another problem: If the password is incorrect but they are not out of tries, you `break`. If the password is incorrect and they are out of tries, you also `break`. In fact, you don't even get to the `if (wrongPasswords == 3)` test unless the password is *correct* because of the `break` above the `if`!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hi, so I edited my code quite a bit and there's still one bug that I can't figure out. How do I get the program to exit if the user's password is still incorrect after 3 tries? Right now, it just goes on to the next section of my program. Is there a way to terminate the program?

Comment: @wangowango Use a return statement, you are just exiting function without any returning value in your case of void function, you don't need to specify any values.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try with *bool* instead of *void* function. Return true if password was correct, exit program after failing three times. For example,

```
bool getPassword() {
    for ( int attempts = 0; attempts < 3; ++attempts ) {
        std::string password;
        std::cout << "Enter your password: " << password << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, password);

        if ( password == "1" ) {
            std::cout << "Welcome!";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your main function, call `getPassword()` function,

```
int main() {
    if ( !getPassword() )
        return true;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This seems more elegant and would have used bool instead of void, unless you have reason not to.

Comment: You missed the braces for the `if` statement.

Comment: It lets in even on the wrong password. `return true` is indented, but it's not part of the `if` statement's body.

Comment: The only problem is the missing braces enclosing the `if ( password == "1" )` block. Good job choosing `getline` (you would still validate `if (!(std::getline(std::cin, password))) { /* handle user-generated EOF */ }`

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issue and for both you and @krisz providing answers. Always strive to be as correct as possible (and informative) when answering. You step into the role of teacher -- so be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another snippet:

```
bool tryLogin() {
    string pwd = "hello";
    string inp;
    int tries = 1;
    while (true) {
        cout << "\nEnter password ";
        cin >> inp;
        if (inp.compare(pwd) == 0) return true;
        ++tries;
        if (tries > 3) {
            cout << "\n Max number of trials exceeded\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << endl << (tryLogin() ? "Login successful" : "Can't login") << endl;
}
```